# updating an observable inside the model but without triggering the associated events of the model in knockout

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

hi i have a model in knockout holded by a variable :

```
var knockoutObject = knockoutObservable;
```

if i do this:

```
knockoutObject(newValue);
```

it triggers the binding events for knockout(?) and the ui is refreshed
how can i update the value of the knockoutObservable without affecting the entire screen? in other words: updating the value on the model but not updating the UI

I know its kind of weird because that's the deal with MVVM but i need it for a specific scenario...

edit:
what im trying to do:
I have a few jsTrees on the screen. they are bounded to the model. 
when I update a certain observable in the model all the trees are being re rendered and are closed to there default state. it gives me a bad user experience
so because the UI is already updated with the correct values when i chane a value in a tree (this is how i built it) i dont need knockout to rerender the trees. just the value on the model.

i have a custom binding handler for the trees:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.Tree
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [throttle](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html) to delay execution - but you probably want to approach the entire problem differently. With some more insight into what you're trying to solve, we can probably suggest a better alternative.

UPDATE (from comments):

**The binding ideally should not recreate the jsTree plugin, but simply modify it's internals. This is the preferred way of doing it.**

If you can't do that, see if you can cache the state in the binding and recreate the jsTree with previous state

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just change the update on your custom binding to simply not collapse the trees?

Comment: its not collapsing the trees.. its rendering the jsTree plugin again.. which comes collapsed by default. I can't tell it to just not render the plugin, because sometimes I need him too... only this scenario I don't

Comment: The binding ideally should not recreate the jsTree plugin, but simply modify it's internals. If you can't do that, see if you can cache the state in the binding and recreate the jsTree with previous state

Comment: i would. but that means going over all trees in the screen... this is a bad work around for me... saveing a few states (don't know how many its dynamic) and then recreating it. not so much fun... :)

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle with your scenario? You shouldn't have to update all the trees code - just the binding you create.

Comment: OK so I solved it in this approach: "The binding ideally should not recreate the jsTree plugin" in my custom binding I check to see if the element already holds a jsTree if so i will not recreate it. just update the data I need to update using the jsTree methods. thanks for the help

Comment: no because that's not what solved it. can you please edit the answer or write a new one which basicly says what your comment said and then ill mark it as the answer?